# Is an inspectable promise.catch an anti-pattern?

Tags: redux, error-handling, promise, middleware

My use case: I'm using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and custom redux middleware for api fetching, and using [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) for writing forms quickly (my client's site has hundreds of forms).

I want to be able to 1) handle errors via promise.catch inside of Formik, and 2) if the error is NOT handled in Formik, have a later middleware catch the error (ONLY if the error has not already been caught).

**Problems:**

- native promises have no way to determine whether `.catch` has been called on them
- [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) has `.isFulfilled`, `.isRejected`, `.isPending`, and `.isCancelled` synchronous inspection methods, but not `.isCaught`

**Possible solution:**

I came up with the following, but want to know if there are any caveats with this approach. I can't think of any.

This solution is largely based off of [this tutorial](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/317/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-promise-has-been-fulfilled-rejected-or-resolved).

```
function inspectable(promise) {
  let isHandled = false;
  let isFulfilled = false;
  const result = {
    then: (fnc) => (promise.then(data => {
      isFulfilled = true;
      return Promise.resolve(data);
    })).then(fnc),
    catch: (fnc) => (promise.catch(err => {
      isHandled = true;
      isFulfilled = true;
      return Promise.reject(err);
    })).catch(fnc)
  };
  result.isHandled = () => isHandled;
  result.isFulfilled = () => isFulfilled;
  return result;
}
```

Then running the following test gives these results:

```
const x = inspectable(Promise.reject('reject me'));

x.isHandled();
>> false

x.catch(err => {
  // suppress errors
});

setTimeout(() => console.log(x.isHandled()), 10);
>> true
setTimeout(() => console.log(x.isFulfilled()), 10);
>> true
```

This seems to give me what I need - I can determine whether a promise has had `.catch` called on it when handling it in a later middleware. Any red flags to using this approach?

Comment: The usual design pattern for promises is that if you handle the error, then you don't let the rejected promise propagate onwards.  So, then the higher level caller knows that if they see the rejected promise, then the error hasn't been handled yet.  That would be my design suggestion.

Comment: Also, as soon as anyone chains the returned promise (as is often done when coordinating multiple asynchronous operations), the value will become a normal promise, not your inspectable and the result will be gone.  I would not recommend this at all.

Comment: Good call, still, I wish there were a way to automatically catch uncaught errors in middleware. Right now we have to manually add `.catch` statements to hundreds of api calls - most of those cases are just for general errors (`failed to fetch`, etc.). And if you forget the `.catch` statement on one of those requests... the user isn't notified (our notification system ties into `catch` statements). Sounds like a case for unit tests... :)

Comment: Adding "hundreds" of `.catch()` statements in middleware sounds like you're not doing something correctly unless you're just complaining about having to add appropriate error handling.  We'd have to see real code examples (probably in a new question) to advise further.

Comment: FYI, the koa framework is express-like, but built around promises and it will catch promise rejections in middleware for you allowing you to centralizing middleware rejection handling.   Without changing your framework, a single utility method could do this for you in Express too.

Comment: this is the action where I need to check error handling:

`return dispatch(apiRequest(...))`

`apiRequest` is a thunk action that returns a `fetch` request. Error handling is up to each individual action in this case.

Comment: We'd have to see a lot more code to know what to suggest including `apiRequest()` and multiple examples of the usage context.  As I already said, that would be appropriate for a new question.